# Libgdx handle SVG

Tags: java, android, svg, libgdx

I want to know if there is a possibility to use svg graphics with libgdx. I know that Libgdx itself can not handle svgs but is there a possibility with an extension or a method which pre creates PNG's/JPG's out of the SVG's and pass them to Libgdx?

Comment: Can't you just open the SVG with a software like PhotoShop/Gimp, export as PNG, use the PNGs (within a TextureAtlas)?

Comment: Problem is that the textures are heavy files (about 1440x2565) so that they are sharp :/

Answer (score 1):

No, currently not supported.

For simple shape rendering you can use [ShapeRenderer](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/ShapeRenderer.html). You can't parse `.svg` file because of cross platform support.

For android you can use https://github.com/pents90/svg-android

Also check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322995/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-vector-graphics-into-libgdx-development), It may be helpful.

Comment: Does this tools just make a png out of my svg?

Comment: You can draw .svg file on android using that tool. you can also use [sharp](https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp) a svg-andorid fork

Comment: But than it is possible to use svgs in with libgdx?

Comment: Is it possible to ask/vote for a svg implementation by libgdx?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: not sure you may ask on LibGDX forum ? I don't think there is any plan/milestone for the same ?

Comment: :/ why don't they implement it :(

Comment: not able to implement due to cross platform support, check this [issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libgdx/issues/507)

Comment: what is with this, cant I just tuse this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580391/android-studio-1-3-svg-to-png-conversion

Comment: No we can't use, At build time there is conversion from vector images to PNGs. And it's with Android, we need it for LibGDX.