# mergeDebugResources error in android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, png

I am working in Android Studio which shows the error like _File name must end with `*.xml or *.png_`. I am using `_*.pkm_ file`. My Gradle Build version in `_1.2.2_` . How to solve it? Help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to conver .pkm file to .png

check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/ETC1.html

> Methods for encoding and decoding ETC1 textures.
>
> The standard for the ETC1 texture format can be found at
>   http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture.txt
>
> The PKM file format is of a 16-byte header that describes the image
>   bounds followed by the encoded ETC1 texture data.

than after inside your project directory clean build your project and run.

Please check [this SO answe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533861/android-using-svg-in-res-leads-to-error-the-file-name-must-end-with-xml-or/34116246)r for more detail.