# AAPT err: libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: android

After updating Android Studio 2.0 with Gradle version 2.10, I am getting this below metioned issue.

**Note**:The same project working fine in Android Studio 2.0 with Gradle version 2.8

I have reviewed all my images, don't know what will be the problem.

The same problem has posted in [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/u/111777141735323711757/)

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareAppcorlibAdaptersReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareAppcorlibAmpReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareAppcorlibNetClientReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareAppcorlibReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareAppcorlibRtfconverterReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareAppcorlibTradingReleaseLibrary
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 1563428392): libpng error: Not a PNG file
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.951 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: Is that 1563428392 a resource id? If so you can check what resource is giving you that error.

Comment: @PedroOliveira no, its not a resource id.

Comment: You can convert it to hex and try finding it in R.java.

Comment: 1. Delete the whole `build` folder from root and from within app and try again. 2. If #1 doesn't help: run `gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace --debug` from command line which will likely output the exact command/file name causing the problem. See [Logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At last, I resolved the issue with the help of this link [refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile/22747902#22747902)

Goto terminal and execute the below mentioned command to know the details about the issue

```
gradlew assembleDebug --info
```

It will show you the info about the issue or warning. In my project i have got some issues like, some files crunching failed issue.

Steps to resolve:

1. Install the ImageMagick tool [download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
2. To remove the iCCP chunk from the PNG image

   Click down the "Shift" key and right click on the folder which is having images

   Select "Open command window here" option

   In the command terminal type `mogrify *.png`

(e.g. D:\AndroidProjects{your_project_folder}\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi>mogrify *.png)

3. Now go to your project terminal execute the command  `gradlew assembleDebug --info`,Hope all your warnings and failed to convert issues are removed.